# Do Klingons do surgery without anaesthesia?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, klingon

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E11](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6011052/) ***The Wolf Inside*** - we see Tyler's flashbacks of what were thought to be torture - were in fact surgery.

[image]

[image]

Vulture writer [Mallory Ortberg](http://www.vulture.com/author/Mallory%20Ortberg/) [comments](http://www.vulture.com/2018/01/star-trek-discovery-recap-season-1-episode-11.html):

> The procedure was apparently performed without anesthesia, supposedly to demonstrate how METAL Klingons are, but that is genuinely counterproductive from a medical standpoint!

My question is: **Do Klingons do surgery without anaesthesia?**

Comment: ISTR Worf frequently refuse any painkiller when undergoing a medical procedure. It is not the Klingon way.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister - could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: Klingon biology might be different than human biology.  We are omnivorous, and hominid.  In the episode "genesis" the humans were devolving toward lemur, while the klingon was moving toward more massive (200kg is about 441 lb) pinnacle predator, armored and had an exoskeleton.  Exoskeletons belong to insects, arachnids (spiders), crustaceans(lobster-like), mollusks(snail-like), echinoderms (starfish), tardigrades(!!), nematodes (roundworms), and annelids(flatworm).  This suggests maybe Klingons were non-aquatic, bear-sized, crustaceans before the augment virus pandemic forced mamal  mutation.